# how to use git reflog --expire command?

Tags: git

By default git reflog is returning results from last 90 days. How I can go beyond it? I tried different ways to set --expire but its throwing error. Whats the proper way of using it?

I tried

```
git reflog --expire=all
fatal: unrecognized argument: --expire=all
```

then

```
$ git reflog --expire=2022-01-01 12:12:00
fatal: invalid object name '12'.
```

then

```
$ git reflog --expire=2022-01-01
fatal: unrecognized argument: --expire=2022-01-01
```

Comment: According to the documentation at https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog `--expire` is only applicable for the `expire` reflog-subcommand: `git reflog expire [--expire=<time>] ...`

Answer (score 4):

Users should ordinarily *not* run `git reflog expire` themselves.  Instead, they should normally let `git` commands run `git gc --auto`, or if they want to force a garbage-collection pass now, run `git gc` themselves without `--auto`.

To make reflog entries last *longer* than the default 30 and 90 days, use `git config` to set the *expiry* values, as described in [the `git gc` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc).<sup>1</sup>  The main two knobs to set are `gc.reflogExpire` and `gc.reflogExpireUnreachable`, which default to `90.days` and `30.days` respectively.

Note that once an entry has passed its expiration date, the *next* `git gc` that actually does anything is the one that removes the entries.  Once they're gone, they are gone forever (unless you restore them from a system backup).

---

<sup>1</sup>Hiding these details in `git help gc` (though they also appear in the `git config` documentation) is one of the ways Git maintains its air of inscrutability.  Seriously though, they're in that document because it's `git gc` that handles the configured expiration.  That's why you normally don't run `git reflog expire` at all.